# Libraries for Visio type functionality

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, diagramming

Im currently looking for c# libraries that will provide visio like diagramming functionality. As fundamentals, I need to be able to place shapes on a canvas, define connection points on those shapes (points to which connection lines can be connected) and be able to draw connecting lines between them. Im not averse to paying for a solution, on the basis that it will probably work out cheaper than having to develop one myself. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Look at NShape or Diagram.NET on Codeplex.

Answer (score 0):

[Open Diagram on Codeplex](http://opendiagram.codeplex.com/)

Comment: "Open Diagram is the definitive open source .net diagramming component library for the .Net framework **winforms** environmet"

Answer (score 0):

Late answer but may help others;  I have worked on a similar project in past and we had used canvas as designer surface; as done in this CodeProject article -

> [WPF Diagram Designer - Part 4](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFDiagramDesigner_Part4.aspx)

One more project based on this, it allows you to draw digital items (Seven segment display, 4-Bit-Shift register, Full add,...), connect them with lines etc.-

> http://simulo.codeplex.com/